# msdeploy error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed. using IIS7, TFS2010, VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Using Visual Studio 2012, TFS 2010, IIS7

Getting the following errors when I try to build/deploy:

```
Any CPU | Test
1 error(s), 1 warning(s)

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets      
(4253): Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("server1") using
the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the 
correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that 
the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. Learn more 
at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

*snip warning*

Other Errors and Warnings
2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please 
add the "/m" switch.
TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.
```

- I verified the site exists in IIS
- I verified I have username and password correct (I'm able to log onto server)
- User is an admin on tfs server

I don't have VS2012 on my tfs server, but someone copied their C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0 folder to the tfs server to fix another build issue a while back. I copied the same folder to "server1", did not change the error message.

It still creates the build, just does not deploy.

Comment: I would suggest that you move towards creating a release pipeline and away from deploying directly from a build. It is much more secure and efficient to use a dedicated tool like Release Management for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did not have space between my password and the next build argument, so the password was technically wrong.

```
/p:UserName=scw /p:Password=12345/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
/p:UserName=scw /p:Password=12345 /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

Answer (score 13):

We were able to resolve the issue by the following steps:

- Highlight the website in IIS Manager
- In the Features view, open up IIS Manager Permissions
- Verify that the user you are deploying as has been added. If not, click Allow User and add it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case, I had to make sure that my domain was included in my login.

Comment: I'm using VS2022 and get the same errors however deploying from visual studio code using azure plugin works fine. In visual studio code I did nothing special for it to work, i could use both programs, one for editing (because of IntellySense) and the other for deploy but it is just an ugly hack...

It's not my first webapp, so i have some experience using Azure, my problem here is the above things you wrote make no sense to me. Perhaps the naming and interface changed because I found your text in microsoft documentation ....

Comment: You could very well be correct - It's been a number of years since I wrote this response; I hope it's not misleading to anyone nowadays. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if you specify the wrong site name.  You have to enter the name as it appears in the IIS Connections, e.g. `Default Web Site`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue in one environment and not in another. My issue was that I did not prepend the computer name to the user name (i.e. p:UserName=testserver\admin vs p:UserName=admin). In my working environment, both servers utilized an account via Active Directory, so this wasn't an issue. Lesson learned!

Answer (score -6):

I would recommend against using Team Build to do a deployment. I assume that it is doing the compilation for each deployment. This is not a good idea as things can change between builds as compilers are not 100%. You would be better doing a binary deployment with a deployment tool. I have used Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 very effectively to deploy the same binaries from Dev->QA->Prod...

You can get information on how from [Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2013](http://nkdalm.net/ProALMwithVS13).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will have to check into that.

Comment: I'm sorry but what in the world are you talking about???  "...things can change between builds as compilers are not 100%."